# input type radio checked resets after pages loads

Tags: angular

I'm having a input of type radio in a forloop template like this:

```
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="numberOfOptions | reverse" let-item>
        <input id="rating{{item}}" type="radio" name="rating" value="{{item}}" [(ngModel)]="alreadySelected" [checked]="item === defaultSelected">
        <label for="rating{{item}}">{{item}}</label>
    </ng-template>
```

where defaultSelected is a property in my component:

```
defaultSelected: number
```

When the page reloads the correct radio is selected but then suddenly it just resets to none selected.

Comment: I think that you don't have to bind to the checked property, as NgModel will automatically handle it for you.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't bind

Comment: On your code you're applying the NgModel to 'alreadySelected', but in your controller you have 'defaultSelected'. Isn't this the problem?

Comment: When you I load the page the correct input fields are enabled but then it just  removes. Even when I set the alreadySelected on the same number.

Comment: But what is alreadySelected versus defaultSelected? You just need one of them, and place it on NgModel.

Answer (score 0):

The property was defined as:

```
set alreadySelected(value) {
    this._alreadySelected = value
    this.notify.emit(value);  
}
```

But there was no getter for it so I added the getter like this:

```
get alreadySelected(): number {
    return this._alreadySelected
}
```

and then the condition for is checked like this:

```
<input id="rating{{item}}" type="radio" name="rating" [value]="item" [(ngModel)]="alreadySelected" [checked]="item == alreadySelected">
```

Then when I have a defaultSelected because it's optional:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.defaultSelected) {
        this.alreadySelected = this.defaultSelected
    }
}
```